# How to find characters in a string

Tags: substring, indexof

I am trying to use a string from textbox1 and look for the 3rd 'e' and tell the index of it
for example, if somebody typed in cheese, then the index of it

so far, i have

```
Dim word As String = TextBox2.Text
Dim x As String
Dim counter As Integer
Dim Letter As String
Dim word1 As String
x = 0
word1 = word.ToLower()
Do
    If word1.Substring(x, 1) = "e" Then counter = counter + 1 And x = x + 1
Loop Until counter = 3 Or counter <> 3
If counter <> 3 Then MsgBox("There are only " & counter & "e's in the inputted string") Else ListBox2.Items.Add(Letter)
```